# mostrar Select de sql con extJS en .net

Tags: javascript, html5, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, extjs

alguien me puede ayudar estoy usando extJS pero no puedo mostrar los datos de una tabla de mi base de datos en un grid uso MVC de .Net, me marca este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

app.js

```
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {


    storeId: 'myData',
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        fields: [
            { name: 'EmpleadoId', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'NombreEmpleado', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'DirectorId', type: 'int' }]
    }),

    proxy: {
        type: 'json',
        url: 'TestController/writeRecord'
    }

});
this.grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'GridView App',
    url: 'TestController/writeRecord',
    //store: store,
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('myData'),
    columns: [
        {
            header: 'EmpleadoId', width: 100,
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'EmpleadoId'
        },
        {
            header: 'NombreEmpleado', width: 100,
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'NombreEmpleado'
        },
        {
            header: 'DirectorId', width: 100,
            sortable: true, dataIndex: 'DirectorId'
        }
    ],
    stripeRows: true,
    //height:250,
    width: 800,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Controller

```
public class TestController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Test
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult writeRecord()
        {

            Response.Write("Survey Completed!");
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=PC;Database=TestPersona;Trusted_Connection=yes;");


            string sqlquery = "SELECT EmpleadoId,NombreEmpleado,DirectorId FROM Empleados";
            SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery, conn);

            DataSet myData = new DataSet();
            cmd.Fill(myData, "Empleados");


            conn.Open();
            conn.Close();

            return Json(myData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }


    }
```

Vista

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="~/Content/charts-all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: en primer lugar, ¿Te llegan los datos en JSON?

Comment: no se, puesto que genera error el archivo app.js y ya no puedo ver si hay respuesta del metodo que devuelve el json

Comment: un breakpoint ayudaría...

Comment: tal vez es un error de sintaxis de mi JS pero no lo ubico

Comment: coloca todo el app.js :)

Comment: @fredyfx lo que puse arriba es todo lo que tengo en mi js

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80410/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-ivxn).